# How to make a thumbnail from a photo taken from camera?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-camera

In my app I'm using external camera app to make photo and save it to sdcard, and I need a square thumbnail of this photo. I've managed to crop to square the thumbnail sent back by camera in the intent, but since i'm saving photo to disk, the intent is empty, and my old method to make picture square `Bitmap cropped = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, min, min)` throws an OutOutMemory exception.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Bitmap ThumbImage = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath), THUMBSIZE, THUMBSIZE);
```